# Is there a free song recognition API?

Tags: gratis, api, artificial-intelligence, shazam

I'm looking for a free song recognition API that's not on rapidapi as I don't want to give out my credit card info.

Answer (score 1):

SoundHound is an app I have used for years that makes a playlist for you on Spotify and there’s no charge. Find it in the App Store! It works great...very few songs are not recognized and it will even keep the song recorded that it can’t find and you can run it through at a later date.

It’s also available for Android devices so it’s great for those who use both iPhones and a windows base laptop...

Comment: Does SoundHound provide a "free API"?

Answer (score 0):

Google [hum to search](https://metro.co.uk/2020/10/19/googles-hum-to-search-feature-actually-works-13444210/) feature is available at no cost